# Offset & Center Container w/Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Im trying to center the header and input field with bootstrap. I cant get the input field to center with the header. If anyone has a better way of doing this let me know.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1 class="display-4 text-center">Weight Converter</h1>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            id="lbsInput"
            type="number"
            class="form-control form-control-lg"
            placeholder="Enter Weight..."
          />
        </div>
      </form>
      <div id="output">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4>Grams:</h4>
            <div id="gramsOutput"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you at least post the code that closes out the tags you start here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have incomplete HTML and no CSS. But based on what you have, a simple `margin: auto;` in CSS should center the element for you.

If you want more control you should look into flexbox. post more code and you'll get more help.

EDIT: thanks for the code: this works to center the input. I just verified it. let me know if you need any more help. cheers

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 class="display-4 text-center">Weight Converter</h1>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group" id="centerParent">
            <input
              id="lbsInput"
              type="number"
              class="form-control form-control-lg"
              placeholder="Enter Weight..."
            />
          </div>
        </form>
        <div id="output">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4>Grams:</h4>
              <div id="gramsOutput"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<style>

#centerParent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

</style>
```

Comment: I tried out `margin: auto;` without any luck but I have updated the question with the rest of my code.